# Overwrite point meta value after explicit definition

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, color, pgfkeys

I want do some surface/mesh plots in pgfplots with a kind of logarithmic axis for positive and negative values. This is sometimes called a `symlog` colormap transformation, i.e. a logarithmic axis for the colorbar with positive and negative values and a linear part around zero. That was successfull so far. However, I could not manage to overwrite the point meta value that is given from a file (in a certain row). How can this be done? In the following code, `point meta = {1},` just does nothing, as the the meta value read from the table seems to have precedence.

Can this behavior be changed, and can I reuse the already assigned meta value, like `point meta = {2*meta}` or similar?

---

### EDIT

I think I found a solution. I can plot it in 3d and asign the meta value to `z`, and then use the z coordinate in the colormap transformation. I'll try it out and post an answer myself.

```
\documentclass{standalone}


\def\infile{infile.txt}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}



\pgfplotsset{
  symlog colormap trafo/.code={
    \pgfkeysalso{%
      y coord trafo/.code={%
        \pgfmathparse{##1>#1 ? 1+3*ln(##1<0.001?1: (##1/#1))/ln(10*sqrt(10)) : (##1<-#1 ? -1-3*ln(##1>-0.001?1: (-##1/#1))/ln(10*sqrt(10))      : ##1/#1)}
      },
      y coord inv trafo/.code={%
        \pgfmathparse{##1>1 ? exp((##1-1)/3*ln(10*sqrt(10)))*#1 : (##1<-1 ? -exp((-##1-1)/3*ln(10*sqrt(10)))*#1  : ##1*#1)}
      },
    }%
  },
  symlog colormap/.code n args={3}{
    \pgfkeysalso{
      colorbar style={
        symlog colormap trafo={#1},
        point meta min={#2},
        point meta max={#3},
      },
    % point meta is useless here!!!!!
    %point meta={y>#1 ? 1+3*ln(y<0.001?1: (y/#1))/ln(10*sqrt(10)) : (y<-#1 ? -1-3*ln(y>-0.001?1: (-y/#1))/ln(10*sqrt(10)) : y/#1)}
    point meta = {1},
    }%
  },
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%height=4cm,
             width = \linewidth,
             %axis equal image,
             grid=major, 
             axis on top,
             colorbar,
             colormap/hot2,  % linthr, min, max, 
             symlog colormap={142.3}{-4500}{4500}, % threshold is computed as      max * 10^-1.5
             mesh/ordering=y varies,
             %axis equal image,
             colorbar style={
                             scaled ticks=false,
                             ytick={-4500,-450,-142.3,0,142.3,450,4500}, 
                             },
             tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
             enlargelimits=false,
             ]

      \pgfplotstableread{\infile}\datatable
            \addplot[
                     mesh/rows=100, surf,  
                     point meta=explicit,
                     %shader = interp,
                     shader=faceted,           
                    ] table [
                             x index = 0,
                             y  index= 1,
                             meta expr =\thisrowno{2}/10,
                             %meta expr = { \thisrowno{2}/10>400 ?   ln(abs(\thisrowno{2}/10))*400/ln(400)     :  (\thisrowno{2}/10 < -400 ? -ln(abs(-\thisrowno{2}/10))*400/ln(400)      : \thisrowno{2}/10)},
                            ]   from \datatable {};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

example infile.txt

```
x y meta
-0.464037 -1.38793 101.927
-0.464037 -1.22858 63.3195
-0.464037 -1.06922 23.3559
-0.464037 -0.909872 -20.5089
-0.464037 -0.75052 -65.953
-0.464037 -0.591168 -112.88
-0.464037 -0.431816 -151.893
-0.464037 -0.272463 -65.6995
-0.464037 -0.113111 3721
-0.464037 0.0462407 6930.78
-0.464037 0.205593 8729.32
-0.464037 0.364945 10371
-0.464037 0.524297 11670.3
-0.464037 0.683649 12613.7
-0.464037 0.843001 12861
-0.464037 1.00235 12776.4
-0.464037 1.16171 12108.1
-0.464037 1.32106 11130.7
-0.464037 1.48041 9662.74
-0.464037 1.63976 7949.07
-0.464037 1.79911 5882.67
-0.464037 1.95847 3678.8
-0.464037 2.11782 1310.1
-0.464037 2.27717 -1149.99
-0.464037 2.43652 -3656.71
-0.464037 2.59587 -6264.58
-0.464037 2.75523 -9257.72
-0.464037 2.91458 -13684.6
-0.464037 3.07393 -23905.2
-0.464037 3.23328 -31114.5
-0.464037 3.39263 -28435.8
-0.464037 3.55199 -12664.4
-0.464037 3.71134 -2034.44
-0.464037 3.87069 2296.67
-0.464037 4.03004 4581.2
-0.464037 4.18939 6494.72
-0.464037 4.34875 8901.13
-0.464037 4.5081 11294.4
-0.464037 4.66745 13712.5
-0.464037 4.8268 16742.4
-0.464037 4.98616 23810.3
-0.464037 5.14551 34622.6
-0.464037 5.30486 33146.1
-0.464037 5.46421 25525.4
-0.464037 5.62356 24778.3
-0.464037 5.78292 27677.8
-0.464037 5.94227 24634.8
-0.464037 6.10162 18625.8
-0.464037 6.26097 11743.4
-0.464037 6.42032 4405.53
-0.464037 6.57968 -3080.68
-0.464037 6.73903 -10406.6
-0.464037 6.89838 -17052.6
-0.464037 7.05773 -21416.5
-0.464037 7.21708 -27375.1
-0.464037 7.37644 -32172.5
-0.464037 7.53579 -34922.1
-0.464037 7.69514 -24427.8
-0.464037 7.85449 -11148.7
-0.464037 8.01384 -6042.41
-0.464037 8.1732 -3757.29
-0.464037 8.33255 -2499.97
-0.464037 8.4919 -1912
-0.464037 8.65125 -1377.1
-0.464037 8.81061 -1108.59
-0.464037 8.96996 -840.085
-0.464037 9.12931 -662.9
-0.464037 9.28866 -494.559
-0.464037 9.44801 -364.402
-0.464037 9.60737 -243.11
-0.464037 9.76672 -142.34
-0.464037 9.92607 -49.8954
-0.464037 10.0854 29.285
-0.464037 10.2448 100.031
-0.464037 10.4041 161.315
-0.464037 10.5635 213.545
-0.464037 10.7228 258.869
-0.464037 10.8822 294.296
-0.464037 11.0415 324.875
-0.464037 11.2009 344.706
-0.464037 11.3602 361.481
-0.464037 11.5196 366.801
-0.464037 11.6789 370.63
-0.464037 11.8383 362.455
-0.464037 11.9976 354.148
-0.464037 12.157 333.093
-0.464037 12.3164 312.038
-0.464037 12.4757 278.404
-0.464037 12.6351 243.528
-0.464037 12.7944 196.15
-0.464037 12.9538 145.842
-0.464037 13.1131 198.935
-0.464037 13.2725 294.299
-0.464037 13.4318 275.408
-0.464037 13.5912 248.291
-0.464037 13.7505 205.995
-0.464037 13.9099 161.831
-0.464037 14.0692 115.677
-0.464037 14.2286 70.0402
-0.464037 14.3879 24.5834
-0.649651 -1.38793 107.153
-0.649651 -1.22858 69.411
-0.649651 -1.06922 30.3171
-0.649651 -0.909872 -12.664
-0.649651 -0.75052 -57.3641
-0.649651 -0.591168 -103.675
-0.649651 -0.431816 -142.895
-0.649651 -0.272463 -139.22
-0.649651 -0.113111 1093.74
-0.649651 0.0462407 2198.1
-0.649651 0.205593 2987.89
-0.649651 0.364945 3773.55
-0.649651 0.524297 4550.22
-0.649651 0.683649 5114.77
-0.649651 0.843001 5264.46
-0.649651 1.00235 5257.03
-0.649651 1.16171 4973.15
-0.649651 1.32106 4551.59
-0.649651 1.48041 3911.5
-0.649651 1.63976 3161.24
-0.649651 1.79911 2252.81
-0.649651 1.95847 1271.8
-0.649651 2.11782 203.737
-0.649651 2.27717 -968.117
-0.649651 2.43652 -2287.58
-0.649651 2.59587 -3956.39
-0.649651 2.75523 -6566.74
-0.649651 2.91458 -11864.6
-0.649651 3.07393 -25957.2
-0.649651 3.23328 -35889.3
-0.649651 3.39263 -33175.3
-0.649651 3.55199 -14302.7
-0.649651 3.71134 -1726.44
-0.649651 3.87069 1825.27
-0.649651 4.03004 2777.31
-0.649651 4.18939 3280.65
-0.649651 4.34875 4396.11
-0.649651 4.5081 5721.99
-0.649651 4.66745 7323.04
-0.649651 4.8268 9760.93
-0.649651 4.98616 15030.7
-0.649651 5.14551 28828.1
-0.649651 5.30486 33279.6
-0.649651 5.46421 30796
-0.649651 5.62356 26510.7
-0.649651 5.78292 21126.8
-0.649651 5.94227 14732.9
-0.649651 6.10162 7607.76
-0.649651 6.26097 86.7268
-0.649651 6.42032 -7520.75
-0.649651 6.57968 -14919.1
-0.649651 6.73903 -21845
-0.649651 6.89838 -27676.3
-0.649651 7.05773 -26288.4
-0.649651 7.21708 -28590.2
-0.649651 7.37644 -32842.6
-0.649651 7.53579 -35337.3
-0.649651 7.69514 -24622.6
-0.649651 7.85449 -11191.1
-0.649651 8.01384 -6033.68
-0.649651 8.1732 -3731.83
-0.649651 8.33255 -2469.37
-0.649651 8.4919 -1882.19
-0.649651 8.65125 -1348.52
-0.649651 8.81061 -1082.5
-0.649651 8.96996 -816.476
-0.649651 9.12931 -641.69
-0.649651 9.28866 -475.734
-0.649651 9.44801 -347.717
-0.649651 9.60737 -228.507
-0.649651 9.76672 -129.594
-0.649651 9.92607 -38.9114
-0.649651 10.0854 38.6777
-0.649651 10.2448 107.942
-0.649651 10.4041 167.876
-0.649651 10.5635 218.884
-0.649651 10.7228 263.083
-0.649651 10.8822 297.523
-0.649651 11.0415 327.187
-0.649651 11.2009 346.255
-0.649651 11.3602 362.315
-0.649651 11.5196 367.092
-0.649651 11.6789 370.405
-0.649651 11.8383 361.911
-0.649651 11.9976 353.288
-0.649651 12.157 332.175
-0.649651 12.3164 311.062
-0.649651 12.4757 277.735
-0.649651 12.6351 243.202
-0.649651 12.7944 196.833
-0.649651 12.9538 147.687
-0.649651 13.1131 198.175
-0.649651 13.2725 289.394
-0.649651 13.4318 269.774
-0.649651 13.5912 242.189
-0.649651 13.7505 199.916
-0.649651 13.9099 155.879
-0.649651 14.0692 109.958
-0.649651 14.2286 64.6322
-0.649651 14.3879 19.5124
-0.835266 -1.38793 113.733
-0.835266 -1.22858 77.0743
-0.835266 -1.06922 39.0712
-0.835266 -0.909872 -2.79499
-0.835266 -0.75052 -46.5317
-0.835266 -0.591168 -92.0232
-0.835266 -0.431816 -131.417
-0.835266 -0.272463 -157.699
-0.835266 -0.113111 157.234
-0.835266 0.0462407 497.483
-0.835266 0.205593 899.674
-0.835266 0.364945 1350.62
-0.835266 0.524297 1907.98
-0.835266 0.683649 2315.61
-0.835266 0.843001 2430.46
-0.835266 1.00235 2452.96
-0.835266 1.16171 2312.96
-0.835266 1.32106 2098.26
-0.835266 1.48041 1764.93
-0.835266 1.63976 1370.92
-0.835266 1.79911 889.8
-0.835266 1.95847 358.618
-0.835266 2.11782 -232.579
-0.835266 2.27717 -937.454
-0.835266 2.43652 -1836.02
-0.835266 2.59587 -3195.58
-0.835266 2.75523 -5757.54
-0.835266 2.91458 -11650.7
-0.835266 3.07393 -28117.2
-0.835266 3.23328 -39804.6
-0.835266 3.39263 -36958.1
-0.835266 3.55199 -15639.9
-0.835266 3.71134 -1817.06
-0.835266 3.87069 1346.07
-0.835266 4.03004 1839.46
-0.835266 4.18939 1979.42
-0.835266 4.34875 2671.85
-0.835266 4.5081 3597.23
-0.835266 4.66745 4805.28
-0.835266 4.8268 6680.62
-0.835266 4.98616 10199.7
-0.835266 5.14551 16902.1
-0.835266 5.30486 28648.2
-0.835266 5.46421 37684
-0.835266 5.62356 34863.9
-0.835266 5.78292 30091.6
-0.835266 5.94227 24205.4
-0.835266 6.10162 17520
-0.835266 6.26097 10329.4
-0.835266 6.42032 2926.69
-0.835266 6.57968 -4431.3
-0.835266 6.73903 -11515.4
-0.835266 6.89838 -17969.4
-0.835266 7.05773 -23273.3
-0.835266 7.21708 -28873.1
-0.835266 7.37644 -33156.2
-0.835266 7.53579 -35572.3
-0.835266 7.69514 -24717
-0.835266 7.85449 -11176.3
-0.835266 8.01384 -5986.72
-0.835266 8.1732 -3679.41
-0.835266 8.33255 -2419.24
-0.835266 8.4919 -1836.64
-0.835266 8.65125 -1307.72
-0.835266 8.81061 -1045.96
-0.835266 8.96996 -784.189
-0.835266 9.12931 -612.969
-0.835266 9.28866 -450.514
-0.835266 9.44801 -325.489
-0.835266 9.60737 -209.154
-0.835266 9.76672 -112.765
-0.835266 9.92607 -24.4666
-0.835266 10.0854 50.9917
-0.835266 10.2448 118.284
-0.835266 10.4041 176.426
-0.835266 10.5635 225.813
-0.835266 10.7228 268.522
-0.835266 10.8822 301.661
-0.835266 11.0415 330.116
-0.835266 11.2009 348.183
-0.835266 11.3602 363.302
-0.835266 11.5196 367.366
-0.835266 11.6789 369.997
-0.835266 11.8383 361.087
-0.835266 11.9976 352.051
-0.835266 12.157 330.862
-0.835266 12.3164 309.673
-0.835266 12.4757 276.746
-0.835266 12.6351 242.661
-0.835266 12.7944 197.596
-0.835266 12.9538 149.956
-0.835266 13.1131 197.044
-0.835266 13.2725 282.857
-0.835266 13.4318 262.296
-0.835266 13.5912 234.106
-0.835266 13.7505 191.877
-0.835266 13.9099 148.013
-0.835266 14.0692 102.406
-0.835266 14.2286 57.4964
-0.835266 14.3879 12.8274
-1.02088 -1.38793 121.402
-1.02088 -1.22858 86.0034
-1.02088 -1.06922 49.2777
-1.02088 -0.909872 8.73903
-1.02088 -0.75052 -33.8067
-1.02088 -0.591168 -78.2334
-1.02088 -0.431816 -117.662
-1.02088 -0.272463 -156.432
-1.02088 -0.113111 -219.275
-1.02088 0.0462407 -198.42
-1.02088 0.205593 27.1692
-1.02088 0.364945 320.715
-1.02088 0.524297 762.546
-1.02088 0.683649 1087.53
-1.02088 0.843001 1183.99
-1.02088 1.00235 1217.43
-1.02088 1.16171 1139.98
-1.02088 1.32106 1015.57
-1.02088 1.48041 816.609
-1.02088 1.63976 578.975
-1.02088 1.79911 285.822
-1.02088 1.95847 -45.7842
-1.02088 2.11782 -423.503
-1.02088 2.27717 -908.591
-1.02088 2.43652 -1582.95
-1.02088 2.59587 -2703.3
-1.02088 2.75523 -4983.5
-1.02088 2.91458 -10624.2
-1.02088 3.07393 -28259.4
-1.02088 3.23328 -41486.6
-1.02088 3.39263 -38511.2
-1.02088 3.55199 -15568.3
-1.02088 3.71134 -2246.64
-1.02088 3.87069 680.777
-1.02088 4.03004 1112.1
-1.02088 4.18939 1272.91
-1.02088 4.34875 1840.1
-1.02088 4.5081 2588.46
-1.02088 4.66745 3575.87
-1.02088 4.8268 5093.41
-1.02088 4.98616 7827.52
-1.02088 5.14551 13497.3
-1.02088 5.30486 28658.4
-1.02088 5.46421 41140.1
-1.02088 5.62356 38279.7
-1.02088 5.78292 33317
-1.02088 5.94227 27136.6
-1.02088 6.10162 20085.8
-1.02088 6.26097 12549.3
-1.02088 6.42032 4854.14
-1.02088 6.57968 -2799.5
-1.02088 6.73903 -10231.7
-1.02088 6.89838 -17212
-1.02088 7.05773 -23522.2
-1.02088 7.21708 -28919.4
-1.02088 7.37644 -33183.5
-1.02088 7.53579 -35591.3
-1.02088 7.69514 -24648.3
-1.02088 7.85449 -11049.6
-1.02088 8.01384 -5871.41
-1.02088 8.1732 -3585.47
-1.02088 8.33255 -2342.94
-1.02088 8.4919 -1771.35
-1.02088 8.65125 -1252.91
-1.02088 8.81061 -997.834
-1.02088 8.96996 -742.747
-1.02088 9.12931 -576.502
-1.02088 9.28866 -418.859
-1.02088 9.44801 -297.773
-1.02088 9.60737 -185.176
-1.02088 9.76672 -92.0082
-1.02088 9.92607 -6.72198
-1.02088 10.0854 66.0595
-1.02088 10.2448 130.888
-1.02088 10.4041 186.799
-1.02088 10.5635 234.177
-1.02088 10.7228 275.044
-1.02088 10.8822 306.577
-1.02088 11.0415 333.541
-1.02088 11.2009 350.374
-1.02088 11.3602 364.333
-1.02088 11.5196 367.523
-1.02088 11.6789 369.32
-1.02088 11.8383 359.899
-1.02088 11.9976 350.356
-1.02088 12.157 329.073
-1.02088 12.3164 307.791
-1.02088 12.4757 275.351
-1.02088 12.6351 241.81
-1.02088 12.7944 198.319
-1.02088 12.9538 152.494
-1.02088 13.1131 195.441
-1.02088 13.2725 274.678
-1.02088 13.4318 252.985
-1.02088 13.5912 224.073
-1.02088 13.7505 181.912
-1.02088 13.9099 138.278
-1.02088 14.0692 93.0728
-1.02088 14.2286 48.6866
-1.02088 14.3879 4.5832
-1.2065 -1.38793 129.858
-1.2065 -1.22858 95.8566
-1.2065 -1.06922 60.5644
-1.2065 -0.909872 21.5613
-1.2065 -0.75052 -19.51
-1.2065 -0.591168 -62.519
-1.2065 -0.431816 -101.634
-1.2065 -0.272463 -145.896
-1.2065 -0.113111 -379.322
-1.2065 0.0462407 -504.693
-1.2065 0.205593 -365.742
-1.2065 0.364945 -154.509
-1.2065 0.524297 214.448
-1.2065 0.683649 485.925
-1.2065 0.843001 566.766
-1.2065 1.00235 600.799
-1.2065 1.16171 552.483
-1.2065 1.32106 471.843
-1.2065 1.48041 339.893
-1.2065 1.63976 181.315
-1.2065 1.79911 -15.4899
-1.2065 1.95847 -241.464
-1.2065 2.11782 -502.406
-1.2065 2.27717 -848.863
-1.2065 2.43652 -1340.38
-1.2065 2.59587 -2153.66
-1.2065 2.75523 -3731.15
-1.2065 2.91458 -7217.01
-1.2065 3.07393 -15718.6
-1.2065 3.23328 -22165.3
-1.2065 3.39263 -20171.7
-1.2065 3.55199 -9832.68
-1.2065 3.71134 -3354.79
-1.2065 3.87069 -794.816
-1.2065 4.03004 227.129
-1.2065 4.18939 799.819
-1.2065 4.34875 1362.54
-1.2065 4.5081 2025.66
-1.2065 4.66745 2892.4
-1.2065 4.8268 4229.05
-1.2065 4.98616 6647.36
-1.2065 5.14551 11724.9
-1.2065 5.30486 25897.3
-1.2065 5.46421 38371.1
-1.2065 5.62356 35843.2
-1.2065 5.78292 31143.6
-1.2065 5.94227 25187.4
-1.2065 6.10162 18411.4
-1.2065 6.26097 11350.5
-1.2065 6.42032 4035.99
-1.2065 6.57968 -3288.92
-1.2065 6.73903 -10442.2
-1.2065 6.89838 -17215.2
-1.2065 7.05773 -23411.8
-1.2065 7.21708 -28751
-1.2065 7.37644 -32989.1
-1.2065 7.53579 -35353.9
-1.2065 7.69514 -24239.8
-1.2065 7.85449 -10684.3
-1.2065 8.01384 -5644.92
-1.2065 8.1732 -3435.69
-1.2065 8.33255 -2235.16
-1.2065 8.4919 -1683.4
-1.2065 8.65125 -1183.03
-1.2065 8.81061 -937.528
-1.2065 8.96996 -692.029
-1.2065 9.12931 -532.347
-1.2065 9.28866 -380.976
-1.2065 9.44801 -264.833
-1.2065 9.60737 -156.869
-1.2065 9.76672 -67.6262
-1.2065 9.92607 14.0227
-1.2065 10.0854 83.5961
-1.2065 10.2448 145.491
-1.2065 10.4041 198.752
-1.2065 10.5635 243.757
-1.2065 10.7228 282.448
-1.2065 10.8822 312.09
-1.2065 11.0415 337.3
-1.2065 11.2009 352.683
-1.2065 11.3602 365.283
-1.2065 11.5196 367.449
-1.2065 11.6789 368.268
-1.2065 11.8383 358.251
-1.2065 11.9976 348.117
-1.2065 12.157 326.726
-1.2065 12.3164 305.336
-1.2065 12.4757 273.459
-1.2065 12.6351 240.546
-1.2065 12.7944 198.857
-1.2065 12.9538 155.109
-1.2065 13.1131 193.258
-1.2065 13.2725 264.888
-1.2065 13.4318 241.902
-1.2065 13.5912 212.174
-1.2065 13.7505 170.115
-1.2065 13.9099 126.77
-1.2065 14.0692 82.0545
-1.2065 14.2286 38.3002
-1.2065 14.3879 -5.12043
-1.39211 -1.38793 138.825
-1.39211 -1.22858 106.324
-1.39211 -1.06922 72.5994
-1.39211 -0.909872 35.3536
-1.39211 -0.75052 -3.83643
-1.39211 -0.591168 -44.8499
-1.39211 -0.431816 -82.7206
-1.39211 -0.272463 -127.823
-1.39211 -0.113111 -418.244
-1.39211 0.0462407 -595.089
-1.39211 0.205593 -494.11
-1.39211 0.364945 -331.443
-1.39211 0.524297 -34.1613
-1.39211 0.683649 182.925
-1.39211 0.843001 243.179
-1.39211 1.00235 268.559
-1.39211 1.16171 232.586
-1.39211 1.32106 173.62
-1.39211 1.48041 78.1628
-1.39211 1.63976 -35.9913
-1.39211 1.79911 -176.987
-1.39211 1.95847 -338.527
-1.39211 2.11782 -524.698
-1.39211 2.27717 -767.966
-1.39211 2.43652 -1099.05
-1.39211 2.59587 -1602.05
-1.39211 2.75523 -2434.21
-1.39211 2.91458 -3801.44
-1.39211 3.07393 -5655.52
-1.39211 3.23328 -6818.3
-1.39211 3.39263 -6207.95
-1.39211 3.55199 -4154.73
-1.39211 3.71134 -2145.12
-1.39211 3.87069 -823.714
-1.39211 4.03004 -17.4162
-1.39211 4.18939 550.215
-1.39211 4.34875 1073.24
-1.39211 4.5081 1676.6
-1.39211 4.66745 2477.42
-1.39211 4.8268 3748.7
-1.39211 4.98616 6085.06
-1.39211 5.14551 10573.1
-1.39211 5.30486 17674.5
-1.39211 5.46421 22040
-1.39211 5.62356 21526.8
-1.39211 5.78292 19056.5
-1.39211 5.94227 15721.1
-1.39211 6.10162 12689.9
-1.39211 6.26097 9402.39
-1.39211 6.42032 2964.69
-1.39211 6.57968 -3868.52
-1.39211 6.73903 -10578.9
-1.39211 6.89838 -16388.8
-1.39211 7.05773 -21196.1
-1.39211 7.21708 -25806
-1.39211 7.37644 -29404.1
-1.39211 7.53579 -30913.7
-1.39211 7.69514 -21195.9
-1.39211 7.85449 -9831.69
-1.39211 8.01384 -5292.86
-1.39211 8.1732 -3229.09
-1.39211 8.33255 -2094.61
-1.39211 8.4919 -1571.77
-1.39211 8.65125 -1097.39
-1.39211 8.81061 -864.708
-1.39211 8.96996 -632.036
-1.39211 9.12931 -480.64
-1.39211 9.28866 -337.111
-1.39211 9.44801 -226.952
-1.39211 9.60737 -124.54
-1.39211 9.76672 -39.9269
-1.39211 9.92607 37.4659
-1.39211 10.0854 103.314
-1.39211 10.2448 161.821
-1.39211 10.4041 212.034
-1.39211 10.5635 254.317
-1.39211 10.7228 290.517
-1.39211 10.8822 318
-1.39211 11.0415 341.211
-1.39211 11.2009 354.946
-1.39211 11.3602 366.001
-1.39211 11.5196 367.003
-1.39211 11.6789 366.716
-1.39211 11.8383 356.026
-1.39211 11.9976 345.225
-1.39211 12.157 323.714
-1.39211 12.3164 302.203
-1.39211 12.4757 270.953
-1.39211 12.6351 238.742
-1.39211 12.7944 199.042
-1.39211 12.9538 157.585
-1.39211 13.1131 190.358
-1.39211 13.2725 253.478
-1.39211 13.4318 229.07
-1.39211 13.5912 198.458
-1.39211 13.7505 156.546
-1.39211 13.9099 113.559
-1.39211 14.0692 69.4271
-1.39211 14.2286 26.4165
-1.39211 14.3879 -16.2063
-1.57773 -1.38793 148.031
-1.57773 -1.22858 117.088
-1.57773 -1.06922 85.0239
-1.57773 -0.909872 49.7358
-1.57773 -0.75052 12.9639
-1.57773 -0.591168 -25.1995
-1.57773 -0.431816 -59.0835
-1.57773 -0.272463 -93.519
-1.57773 -0.113111 -182.153
-1.57773 0.0462407 -250.245
-1.57773 0.205593 -268.088
-1.57773 0.364945 -230.877
-1.57773 0.524297 -73.5309
-1.57773 0.683649 40.8107
-1.57773 0.843001 71.0509
-1.57773 1.00235 78.408
-1.57773 1.16171 45.5059
-1.57773 1.32106 -3.29797
-1.57773 1.48041 -77.3443
-1.57773 1.63976 -164.166
-1.57773 1.79911 -269.328
-1.57773 1.95847 -387.544
-1.57773 2.11782 -521.412
-1.57773 2.27717 -687.171
-1.57773 2.43652 -895.449
-1.57773 2.59587 -1174.16
-1.57773 2.75523 -1556.19
-1.57773 2.91458 -2043.19
-1.57773 3.07393 -2527.96
-1.57773 3.23328 -2754.56
-1.57773 3.39263 -2522.29
-1.57773 3.55199 -1901.83
-1.57773 3.71134 -1170.92
-1.57773 3.87069 -529.89
-1.57773 4.03004 -13.0674
-1.57773 4.18939 431.717
-1.57773 4.34875 882.171
-1.57773 4.5081 1426.67
-1.57773 4.66745 2182.35
-1.57773 4.8268 3467.24
-1.57773 4.98616 6135.05
-1.57773 5.14551 13005.5
-1.57773 5.30486 26132.1
-1.57773 5.46421 26851.9
-1.57773 5.62356 24705
-1.57773 5.78292 21520.5
-1.57773 5.94227 17562.5
-1.57773 6.10162 13119.5
-1.57773 6.26097 8095.04
-1.57773 6.42032 2007.77
-1.57773 6.57968 -4397.67
-1.57773 6.73903 -10693.8
-1.57773 6.89838 -16274.2
-1.57773 7.05773 -20971.9
-1.57773 7.21708 -25163
-1.57773 7.37644 -28435.3
-1.57773 7.53579 -29974.3
-1.57773 7.69514 -20399.9
-1.57773 7.85449 -9261.72
-1.57773 8.01384 -4934.39
-1.57773 8.1732 -2986.68
-1.57773 8.33255 -1924.23
-1.57773 8.4919 -1437.47
-1.57773 8.65125 -996.272
-1.57773 8.81061 -779.781
-1.57773 8.96996 -563.289
-1.57773 9.12931 -421.925
-1.57773 9.28866 -287.838
-1.57773 9.44801 -184.682
-1.57773 9.60737 -88.709
-1.57773 9.76672 -9.3919
-1.57773 9.92607 63.1692
-1.57773 10.0854 124.815
-1.57773 10.2448 179.519
-1.57773 10.4041 226.322
-1.57773 10.5635 265.567
-1.57773 10.7228 298.993
-1.57773 10.8822 324.079
-1.57773 11.0415 345.069
-1.57773 11.2009 356.981
-1.57773 11.3602 366.326
-1.57773 11.5196 366.047
-1.57773 11.6789 364.537
-1.57773 11.8383 353.107
-1.57773 11.9976 341.574
-1.57773 12.157 319.933
-1.57773 12.3164 298.291
-1.57773 12.4757 267.723
-1.57773 12.6351 236.274
-1.57773 12.7944 198.7
-1.57773 12.9538 159.689
-1.57773 13.1131 186.61
-1.57773 13.2725 240.484
-1.57773 13.4318 214.565
-1.57773 13.5912 183.028
-1.57773 13.7505 141.319
-1.57773 13.9099 98.7662
-1.57773 14.0692 55.3138
-1.57773 14.2286 13.1589
-1.57773 14.3879 -28.5471
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i only want to do 2D-Plots, I can use the z coordinate as a temporary buffer for the meta value, if the viewing angle is set to be from the top. Probably not the most elegant way, but it works...

Comparison linear / symlog colormap

[image]

The Code of the colormap transformation

```
\pgfplotsset{
  symlog colormap trafo/.code={
    \pgfkeysalso{%
      y coord trafo/.code={%
        \pgfmathparse{##1>#1 ? 1+3*ln(##1<0.001?1: (##1/#1))/ln(10*sqrt(10)) : (##1<-#1 ? -1-3*ln(##1>-0.001?1: (-##1/#1))/ln(10*sqrt(10))      : ##1/#1)}
      },
      y coord inv trafo/.code={%
        \pgfmathparse{##1>1 ? exp((##1-1)/3*ln(10*sqrt(10)))*#1 : (##1<-1 ? -exp((-##1-1)/3*ln(10*sqrt(10)))*#1  : ##1*#1)}
      },
    }%
  },
  symlog colormap/.code n args={3}{
    \pgfkeysalso{
      colorbar style={
        symlog colormap trafo={#1},
        point meta min={#2},
        point meta max={#3},
      },
      % point meta is useless here!!!!!
      point meta={z>#1 ? 1+3*ln(z<0.001?1: (z/#1))/ln(10*sqrt(10)) : (z<-#1 ? -1-3*ln(z>-0.001?1: (-z/#1))/ln(10*sqrt(10)) : z/#1)}
      %point meta = {0},
    }%
  },
}
```